# How to sort gridview using date

Tags: asp.net

How to sort gridview which contains a Date field column .(When I sort the fields gets sort as string variables ).. Taking date from database and placed into a string variable. And  I would  like to sort gridview using date field..

Comment: so why don't you set in the date variable instead of string value?

Answer (score 0):

if you retrieve the value of date field as DATETIME and set it to Datagridview . it could be be sorted automatically.